# C# - Bitmap - Edited png image was saved incorrectly

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, steganography

I'm implementing image steganography, using the LSB of each pixel. If size of secret text is low (<10) it works fine, but it fails for longer texts.

My code:

```
private void processButtonLSB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String dest = destLSBText.Text;
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(dest); // bitmap of the given image
    byte[] temp = GetBytes(this.secretText.Text);
    byte[] secretText = new byte[temp.Length + 1];
    temp.CopyTo(secretText, 0);
    secretText[temp.Length] = 0x0; // adding last 0 byte
    BitArray bits = new BitArray(secretText); // parsing bytes to bits of secret text
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // debug feature
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
    {
        bool bit = bits.Get(i); // getting i bit of secret text
        int x = i / img.Width;
        int y = i % img.Height;

        int argb = img.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb(); // getting argb of the original image
        bool argbBit = argb % 2 != 0; // getting last bit of the pixel
        if (bit && !argbBit || !bit && argbBit) // ensure if we need to make changes
        {
            setBit(ref argb, 0, !argbBit); // changing last bit
            img.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(argb)); // changing bitmap
        }

        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append("0x" + argb.ToString("X4")); // adding modified pixel to debug #2
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString()); // showing all pixels with payload
    saveImage(img, ImageFormat.Png);
}

private void retrieveButtonLSB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String dest = destLSBText.Text;
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile(dest); // bitmap with payload
    List<bool> bits = new List<bool>();
    byte[] foundBytes = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // debug feature
    for (int i = 0; i < img.Width * img.Height; i++) // iterating thru all pixels until zero byte is met
    {
        int x = i / img.Width;
        int y = i % img.Height;
        int argb = img.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb(); // getting argb
        bool bit = argb % 2 != 0; // last bit
        bits.Add(bit);

        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Append(",");
        sb.Append("0x" + argb.ToString("X4")); // adding argb to debug #3

        if (bits.Count % 8 == 0) // checking if last byte is 0x0
        {
            foundBytes = new byte[bits.Count / 8];
            BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(bits.ToArray());
            bitArray.CopyTo(foundBytes, 0);
            if (foundBytes[foundBytes.Length - 1] == 0x0)
                break;
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString()); // showing all pixels with payload

    if (foundBytes != null)
        secretText.Text = GetString(foundBytes);
}
```

`processButtonLSB_Click` creates an image with the given hidden text, and `retrieveButtonLSB_Click` retrieves hidden text from an image.

I added message boxes to detect the pixels on each step, and got the following results

Original image (first pixels)

> 0xFF0C6128,0xFF0C6128,0xFF0B6027,0xFF0B6027,0xFF0A5F26,0xFF0A5F26,0xFF0A5D25,0xFF0A5D25,...

Changed image (from #1)

> 0xFF0C6128,0xFF0C6128,0xFF0B6026,0xFF0B6027,0xFF0A5F26,0xFF0A5F27,0xFF0A5D25,0xFF0A5D24,...

Saved image (from #2)

> 0xFF0C6128,0xFF0C6129,0xFF0B6027,0xFF0B6027,0xFF0A5F27,0xFF0A5F26,0xFF0A5D24,0xFF0A5D24,...

But why? Maybe I have made a mistake? I checked everything twice and did not find anything.

The code that saves the image:

```
private String saveImage(Image img, ImageFormat format)
{
    String path = getSavePath(format);
    if(path != null)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        ImageCodecInfo ici = null;

        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.MimeType == "image/png")
                ici = codec;
        }

        EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters();
        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
        img.Save(path, ici, ep);
        return path;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Other dependencies (I'm sure it's correct)

```
private bool getBit(int b, int bitNumber)
{
    return (b & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0;
}

private void setBit(ref int b, int bitNumber, bool value)
{
    int mask = 1 << bitNumber;
    if(value)
        b |= mask;
    else
        b &= ~mask;
}

private byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
}

private string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on which message box is which; could you add comments to your code so we know which places are generating those message boxes?

Comment: Also, could you explain the precise behavior you expect? I'm not clear on why those hex strings are wrong.

Comment: @MathSquared, added comments to all major things. So hex #2 and #3 should be equal (to retrieve correct secret text), because #2 bitmap was saved to #3.

Comment: Writing this as a comment because you don't provide enough information to verify the answer. In the loops you need to do `y = i % img.Width;` instead of `y = i % img.Height;`. For a small text that has fewer bits than `img.Height` the bug isn't expressed, but for larger texts your modulo is wrong and you end up overwriting on previously written pixels. **Can you please give us an example of a text for which it works, for one it doesn't and the size of the image?**

Comment: @Reti43, it depends on image. If I create a 111x111 image with black pixels and put long text, it works fine. If I use this image https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/3a/c6/f8/3ac6f8a418733f0a4cf7658cd96b9aa0.jpg it fails for long text (as an example text you can use the link of image). So I believe I don't overwrite existing pixels

Comment: The reason why it works for a square image, like 111x111, is because even though if you mix up the height and the width, the calculations are correct. But for the 736x545 image, the link characters + 1 extra byte is 704 bits, which is more than 545 for height. But if you made the change recommended above, i.e., `y = i % img.Width;`, does it not work correctly?

Comment: @Reti43, oh yes! Thank you a lot. I've created breakpoint to check when x and y are 0, and it hit two times. I need to change formula of calculation x and y